# SPARQL : I have individual with multiple values for single object property. How to convert to one record?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

When I query it shows three records for the same individual with three different values for the same object property. So how can I convert to a single record?
[screenshot of query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lBD3.png)
[screenshot of query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lBD3.png)

Comment: use this https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby with `group_concat` as function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed GROUP_CONCAT is your friend. Please find an example below.

### Nick names of US Presidents

[SPARQL : I have individual with multiple values for single object property. How to convert to one record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206791/sparql-i-have-individual-with-multiple-values-for-single-object-property-how)

#### query

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?nickName; SEPARATOR=",") as ?nickNames)
WHERE 
{
  # president
  ?item wdt:P39 wd:Q11696.
  ?item wdt:P1449 ?nickName
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FnickName%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%22%29%20as%20%3FnickNames%29%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20president%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP39%20wd%3AQ11696.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP1449%20%3FnickName%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)

### result

| item | itemLabel | nickNames |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23 | George Washington | American Fabius |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q76 | Barack Obama | Barry |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1124 | Bill Clinton | The Comeback Kid,Slick Willie |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6279 | Joe Biden | Joe |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9588 | Richard Nixon | Dick,Dick Nixon |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9696 | John F. Kennedy | Jack |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9916 | Dwight D. Eisenhower | Ike |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11817 | Andrew Jackson | Old Hickory |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11820 | Martin Van Buren | Old Kinderhook |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11869 | William Henry Harrison | Old Tippecanoe |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11896 | Zachary Taylor | Old Rough and Ready |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q22686 | Donald Trump | The Donald |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q34836 | Ulysses S Grant | “Unconditional Surrender” Grant |